# In Racket, how do I set a lexer to recognize an identifier with a combination of all numbers and letters A-Z AND a-z

Tags: string, racket, lexer

My lexer currently looks like this:

```
#lang racket
(require parser-tools/lex)

(define testLexer
  (lexer
    ["foo" (list 'FOO lexeme)]
    ["bar" (list 'BAR lexeme)]
    [(repetition 1 +inf.0 (char-range #\a #\z)) (list 'ID lexeme)]
    [whitespace (testLexer input-port)]))
```

The 'ID symbols work with all combinations of lower-case letters and numbers.  **I want it to work with upper-case letters too.**  I've tried:

```
[(repetition 1 +inf.0 (char-range #\a #\z) (char-range #\A #\Z) (list 'ID lexeme)]
```

but since repetition takes only two arguments, I can't put in a third one.

There must be some easy way to include upper-case letters too.

**edit:  Also, if there's some way of making sure an identifier starts with a letter (not a number), that would be nice as well**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union` see more in section 1.1. in the [lexer documentataion](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/Lexers.html?q=lexer#%28part._.Creating_a_.Lexer%29)

```
#lang racket
(require parser-tools/lex)

(define testLexer
  (lexer
    ["foo"                (list 'FOO lexeme)]
    ["bar"                (list 'BAR lexeme)]
    [(repetition 1 +inf.0 (union (char-range #\a #\z) (char-range #\A #\Z))) (list 'ID lexeme)]
    [whitespace           (testLexer input-port)]))

(testLexer (open-input-string "AbCDe"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  The only other thing is, how would I get it to only allow identifiers that start with a letter?  Right now, I think 1aBc3XyZ8 would work, for instance.

Comment: No - right now no digits are allowed. Since digits lie outside the a-z range.

Comment: I see.  So, if I wanted digits too, I might do (union (char-range #\a #\z) (char-range #\A #\Z) (char-range #\0 #\9))?  In that case, how would I restrict it to only letters as the first character?

Comment: You would use `concatenation`. Example: `(contenation alfa (repetition 0 +inf.0 alfa-or-digit)` where `alfa` is `(union (char-range #\a #\z) (char-range #\A #\Z))` and `alfa-or-digit` is `(union (char-range #\a #\z) (char-range #\A #\Z) (char-range #\0 #\9))`

Comment: Perfect, I think I'm starting to understand how to deal with strings like that in lexers.  Thanks a ton.